# Why do I need to use #define in code blocks but not on visual studio? (GLFW)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, codeblocks

I'm starting to learn openGL. I prefer to use codeblocks but the setup for GLFW3 is weird in codeblocks. I copied the example code from the documentation of glfw which was for visual studio. But in code blocks I needed to add an extra line `#define GLFW_DLL` to make it work?

```
#define GLFW_DLL
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>


int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

so why do I need to add an extra #define line in codeblocks and not in visual studio to make it work?
I followed [this](http://www.codeincodeblock.com/2011/02/setup-glfw-project-in-codeblock.html) instruction

GLFW documentation example code [here](https://www.glfw.org/documentation.html)

Comment: Use a real C++ compiler, such as [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), and run it in a command line. Read documentation of your C++ compiler, and see [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). Read also the documentation of your debugger (such as [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)). Take inspiration from *existing* open source code (e.g. on [github](http://github.com/)...), e.g. [Qt](https://qt.io/)

Comment: I do not need any defines when I link to glfw. Check your documentation, as suggested.

Comment: From https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/build_guide.html#build_macros: *"GLFW_DLL is required on Windows when using the GLFW DLL, to tell the compiler that the GLFW functions are defined in a DLL."*

Comment: But why do visual studio doesn't need #define GLFW_DLL